# Best practice for obtaining 'this' context

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Being a long time C++/C# developer, I find myself moving a lot of of my JS code into "classes" to group functions and data together.  As those classes handle event though, I'm finding myself having to write "stub" handlers that serve only to route the calls into a class method to provide the proper this context.  So I'm doing things like this:

```
var Manager = {
    foo: 'x',
    bar: 1,

    onClickStub: function(evt) {
        // 'this' refers to HTMLElement event source
        Manager.onClick(evt);
    },

    onClick: function(evt) {
        // 'this' now refers to Manager.
        // real work goes here.
    }
}
```

Is this the normal way of doing things or is there a better way to structure my event handlers while keeping my class organization?

Comment: You should take a look at underscore.js ... there are functions that manage that for you. But you're correct though, you will have to liberally use call / apply to change the context to refer to your JS objects properly as the context of this can change a bit.

Comment: If you're lucky enough to not have to support IE8, you can use [`.bind(Manager)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Your example won't work the way you described. I think you meant `Manager.onClick(evt);`.

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, it's not a good fit for SO's Q&A format. But you should take a look at [this](https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2013/01/this.md) great article, and also Douglas Crockford's [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742) for some really good `this` explications.

Comment: I only have to support mobile browsers in this case.  So the `.bind` options seems like a good one.  Nate, thx for correction.  I updated my sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joseph Silber said in the comments above, I think [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) would be perfect in this case. If you need to support older browsers, you can always add a shim to `Function.prototype.bind` (see an example implementation in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). Then your code could just be:

```
var Manager = {
    var foo: 'x',
    var bar: 1,

    // no more stub!

    onClick: function(evt) {
        // 'this' will refer to Manager.
        // real work goes here.
    }
}

// And when you bind the event handler:
var el = document.getElementById('something');
el.addEventListener('click', Manager.onClick.bind(Manager));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I know to do this is to assign `this` to another variable at the top of your class and then refer to that one throughout the class. But of course this only works if you are not using an anonymous object as your class.

For instance:

```
var Manager = function(){
    var self = this,
    var foo = 'x',
    var bar = 1;

    var onClick = function(evt) {

        console.log(self); // refers to the manager
        console.log(this); // refers to the element the onclick is assigned to

       // If you want this to equal the manager then just do: this = self;
    }
}() // edit: to make this an immediate function
```

In response to a comment below you could attach the onclick like this

```
element.onclick = Manager.onClick;
```

Then in this case the `this` variable in the onclick function is indeed the html element, and the self variable is the Manager function.

Comment: He's using an object not a function

Comment: That is why I have said at the top this works with a function instead of an anonymous object. Also it doesn't make any difference as you can just make it an immediate function if you like, and then it would work in the same way as an object.

Comment: Also he is asking about classes in the original question, in my view a function is a better fit for a class than an object.

Comment: But the whole point was of the question was "Is there a better way to re-establish the correct 'this' context?"  The code in this answer still has that second stub method.

Comment: I've edited the code to reflect more how I think the this variable can be assigned, I don't think binding is really necessary in this instance. It just makes calling the function slightly more convoluted in my opinion.